# Understanding c function pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

Statement:

> *"array of N pointers to functions, returning pointers to functions and returning pointer to integer"*

Can anyone help me with understanding the function prototype for above statement ?

Given answer- `int *(*(*a[N])()) ();`

Please can anyone explain me how we arrive at the above answer ?

Comment: and I've coded for 25 years without knowing that?

Comment: You are not going to need this. And even if you think you do, nobody will understand your code. :-)  In C++ this would likely be solved by using virtual functions and inheritance (and thus hiding all the pointers)

Comment: @BoPersson if only my prof would understand how real world software works :/

Comment: @BoPersson in either C or C++, judicious use of typedefs can make a huge difference in readability. (`using` is even better than `typedef` for modern C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*a[N]
```

is the array of N pointers, calling it x

```
*(x)()
```

returning function pointer, calling it y

```
int *(y) ()
```

is function pointer returning integer

Answer (score 1):

```
int *(*(*a[500])()) ();
```

Translates to:

> declare a as array 500 of pointer to function returning pointer to
>   function returning pointer to int

---

Note:Next time, use this site to understand complex pointer statements http://cdecl.org/